# Frobenius kernel for unipotent algebraic groups

Tags: algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected algebraic group in positive characteristic $p$. If the Frobenius kernel $G_{(p)}=ker (F:G\to G^{(p)})$ is unipotent, do we have $G$ also unipotent?

Comment: What about if $G$ is etale of order prime to $p$? 

Comment: I forgot to say $G$ is connected.

Comment: I suppose $G$ is meant to be affine (otherwise a supersingular elliptic curve would be a counterexample). We can assume the ground field is algebraically closed, and then the *smooth* connected subgroup $G_{\rm{red}}$ inherits the hypothesis, so it contains no nontrivial torus.  Consequently, $G_{\rm{red}}$ must be unipotent, by the structure theory of smooth connected affine groups over alg. closed fields.   Are you interested in non-smooth $G$?  If so then 4.3.1 in Exp. XVII of SGA3 gives the affirmative answer (absence of $\mu_p$ forces unipotence as a group scheme, assuming connectedness).

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in non-smooth ones. Thanks for the reference you gave.